# access oracle enterprise manager from client

Tags: linux, http, oracle

Somebody can tell me how to enable oracle enterprise manager to access from a client?

I install Oracle Express 18.4.0.0.0 in a Centos 7 vm.

Now I access to oracle em by browser on url https://localhost:5500/em from my client throw a ssh putty tunnel If I try from my client a telnet to linux server on 5500 the connection is refused and if i try telnet localhost 5500 the connection is ok.

I've disabled selixux and firewall

What can I do to enable access from an IP pool?

Thanks in advance. Raffaele

Edit:

The output of ss -tlnp is

```
[root@osboxes ~]# ss -tlnp
State      Recv-Q Send-Q    Local Address:Port                          Peer Address:Port              
LISTEN     0      128       127.0.0.1:631                      *:*    users:(("cupsd",pid=1257,fd=12))
LISTEN     0      100       127.0.0.1:25                        *:*    users:(("master",pid=1708,fd=13))
LISTEN     0      128       127.0.0.1:5500                    *:*    users:(("tnslsnr",pid=2458,fd=16))
LISTEN     0      128             *:111                             *:*    users:(("rpcbind",pid=742,fd=4),("systemd",pid=1,fd=46))
LISTEN     0      5           192.168.122.1:53                *:*    users:(("dnsmasq",pid=1786,fd=6))
LISTEN     0      128             *:22                                *:*    users:(("sshd",pid=1258,fd=3))
LISTEN     0      128        [::1]:631                          [::]:*    users:(("cupsd",pid=1257,fd=11))
LISTEN     0      100        [::1]:25                            [::]:*    users:(("master",pid=1708,fd=14))
LISTEN     0      128          [::]:19585                      [::]:*    users:(("ora_d000_xe",pid=2541,fd=9))
LISTEN     0      128          [::]:111                          [::]:*    users:(("rpcbind",pid=742,fd=6),("systemd",pid=1,fd=48))
LISTEN     0      128          [::]:1521                        [::]:*    users:(("tnslsnr",pid=2458,fd=8))
LISTEN     0      128          [::]:22                            [::]:*    users:(("sshd",pid=1258,fd=4))
```

---

in oracle xe 18c I found listener.ora file in /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/listener.ora. 
The file not contains this configuration.

```
    # listener.ora Network Configuration File: /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = osboxes)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

I try a "grep -r 5500 *" in /opt/oracle but I found nothing to help me.

In file diag/tnslsnr/osboxes/listener/trace/listener.log there is this log message

```
diag/tnslsnr/osboxes/listener/trace/listener.log:Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/opt/oracle/admin/XE/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add the output of `sudo ss -tlnp`?

Comment: Thanks, I add a new answer because the output of the command is too long.

Comment: On this site, we are editing the question and add additional info there. This site is not designed like a discussion forum, but like a Question/Answers site.

Answer (score 1):

In the following line you can see that `tnslsnr` is listening on `127.0.0.1:5500`. The IP address `127.0.0.1` is assigned to `lo` (loop back) interface. This means that only local programs can directly access this service.

```
LISTEN     0      128       127.0.0.1:5500                    *:*    users:(("tnslsnr",pid=2458,fd=16))
```

You need to find a file called `listener.ora` that is located in `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/` directory. Here you need to change the `HOST =` from `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` to an IP address that is assigned to an external interface like Ethernet.

Restart the listener after you change that file. You can see  the status with: `lsnrctl status`. Consult Oracle documentation for `tnslsnr` for more details.